# Convert string to a multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

I have a string

```
 var myString = "['Item', 'Count'],['iPad',2],['Android',1]";
```

I need to convert it into an array where:

```
myArray[0][0] = 'Item';
myArray[0][1] = 'Count';
myArray[1][0] = 'iPad';
myArray[1][1] = 2;
```

etc...

The string can vary in length but will always be in the format above. I have tried splitting and splicing and any other "ing" I can think of but I can't get it.

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If the string is certain to be secure, the simplest would be to concatenat `[` and `]` to the beginning and end, and then `eval` it.

```
var arr = eval("[" + myString + "]");
```

---

If you wanted greater safety, use double quotes for your strings, and use `JSON.parse()` in the same way.

```
var myString = '["Item", "Count"],["iPad",2],["Android",1]';

var arr = JSON.parse("[" + myString + "]");
```

This will limit you to supported JSON data types, but given your example string, it'll work fine.

Comment: @RoyiNamir: That was already noted in my answer, but I added the modified string to be clear.

Comment: Great! I've been searching for something like this for awhile! Thanks!

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot for the eval function

Comment: You need to add `;` at the end ( `eval("[" + myString + "];");` )

Comment: `eval` is dangerous, you should not use it on any content that the user can interact with in any way!

Answer (score 1):

write your code like

```
var myString = "[['Item', 'Count'],['iPad',2],['Android',1]]";
```

and just

```
 var arr = eval(myString);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
JSON.parse("[['Item', 'Count'],['iPad',2],['Android',1]]".replace(/\'/g,"\""))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use eval, but in my case it doens't work... My need is convert a string into a array of objects. This is my string (a ajax request result):

```
{'printjob':{'bill_id':7998,'product_ids':[23703,23704,23705]}}
```

when I try:

```
x = "{'printjob':{'bill_id':7998,'product_ids':[23703,23704,23705]}}";
eval(x);
```

I receive a "Unexpected token :" error.

My solution was:

```
x = "{'printjob':{'bill_id':7998,'product_ids':[23703,23704,23705]}}"; 
x = "temp = " + x + "; return temp;"
tempFunction = new Function (x);
finalArray = tempFunction();
```

now a have the object finalArray!

I hope to help

Comment: `new Function(string)` is just as dangerous as eval, make sure that a user cannot change any attributes within the Object`.