# Javascript string to multidimensional array of numbers

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

Ive been reading semilar questions and answers trying to get a solution to this, im working on maps and getting strings that I have to convert to arrays...
I got an string that's given to me as variable that I have access on it as string:

```
coords = '[42.46329472141537,21.46498522471254],[42.463191829327116,21.4654574564449],[42.463524249310545,21.465586246917347],[42.463642970305486,21.465092550106277]';
```

I need this variable to be an array, I tried JSON.parse it's throwing me an error, I tried to map(Number) that's not defined and Ive tried to split, it's deforming my array...
As result I need the array to be in this format:

```
var newCoords = Array(Array([42.46329472141537,21.46498522471254]),Array([42.463191829327116,21.4654574564449]),Array([42.463524249310545,21.465586246917347]),Array([42.463642970305486,21.465092550106277]));
```

Every advice will be helpful.

Comment: Try: ```JSON.parse(`[${coords}]`);```

Comment: Yes it did its job... Is it any likely regex expression?

Comment: No, it is just string concatenation, is the same thing as `JSON.parse("[" + coords + "]");` and this just wraps the string in square brackets to have a valid JSON.

Comment: I didn't know about that, thank you very much, I was looking for a solution since 2 days...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert string to a multidimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13630014/convert-string-to-a-multidimensional-array)

Answer (score 2):

To make it parsable you have to wrap the arrays in a parsable object (object property, another array and so on);

To wrap your string in another object you can take advantage of [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

> Template literals are string literals allowing embedded expressions.
>   You can use multi-line strings and string interpolation features with
>   them. They were called "template strings" in prior editions of the
>   ES2015 specification.

```js
// Wrap arrays in another array to get a parsable object

const coords = '[42.46329472141537,21.46498522471254],[42.463191829327116,21.4654574564449],[42.463524249310545,21.465586246917347],[42.463642970305486,21.465092550106277]';

console.log(JSON.parse(`[${coords}]`));
```

Comment: I allready got the answer on the commens, but you just changed the question it doesent have double brackeds at beginning of the string `[[` it has arrays one after one on the string long...

Comment: Just edited, I thought it was trivial but if you are not used to javascript look at my edit.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `split` function to make an array:

```js
let coords = '[42.46329472141537,21.46498522471254],[42.463191829327116,21.4654574564449],[42.463524249310545,21.465586246917347],[42.463642970305486,21.465092550106277]';
let array = coords.split('],[')
              .map( c=> c.replace(/\[/g, '').replace(/]/g, '').split(','));
console.log(array);
```

Comment: Good ide, using replace after a split... Thank you for answering ^^.